# Amazon Cloud Front: Is it possible to stream a segment of a large file based on some parameters?

Tags: streaming, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to have different URLs pointing into different segments of a single audio/video file.

Player will be browser based. So if the URL based solution is not possible, I am willing to explore the possibility of scripting the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via RTMP.  CloudFront supports RTMP, which allows seeking into a file.